# Email notification for scheduled build that failed with Azure DevOps / VSTS

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

A scheduled build has been setup to run at certian time every day, e.g. 13pm, via Azure DevOps / VSTS.

However, the failed scheduled build doesn't send email notification. It does when the build is kicked off manually or triggered by code changes.

How to enable email notification when the scheduled build failed?

Comment: Releated: When you randomly stop receiveing such emails from on-premise Azure DevOps. Microsoft's support team had no clue on how to solve their own problem: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Azure-DevOps-Server-202001-User-notifi/10403545

Answer (score 11, accepted):

create a new notitication-subscription (category: "build", template: "a build fails") and add the build-reason-field to your filter:

[image]

Comment: How to create New Subscription? Please provide steps?

Comment: @Pingpong click on your profile in the top right corner, select "Notification settings". Then you see an overview of the existing subscriptions and a button on the top (right next to "Notifications" that is called "New subscription". Then you select a Template and click next to customize options for the new subscription like in the screenshot

Comment: How to setup notification for a repo within a project?

Comment: @Pingpong you mean for code-changes from a repo or builds using a certain repo ?

Comment: Within a project, e.g. AzurePipleInsights, in your example, multiple repos can be created. I want to get email notification that failed for a repo within that project.

Comment: @Pingpong i know you can have multiple repos per project, unfortunately you can't filter the build failures by a repo but you can come up with a naming convention for your builds and filter by the name of the build

Comment: Great, How to create an email group that can be used for `Deliver to` so that members can receive email.

Comment: @Pingpong You can't create that in AzureDevOps unfortunately (SecurityGroups can be created, but can't use that for mail distribution), but you can add an email-address that points to a distributionlist you create somewhere else

Comment: Regarding the multiple mail addresses: As stated in this PR https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/7675 it is already possible to specify multiple mail addresses with semicolon. I have tested it and I can confirm it works. Yet, I am not sure why the drop down still says "Custom email address" and the docs are not updated as well.

Comment: For setting up a notification for a specific pipeline within a project you must also add a filter for "Definition name".

Answer (score 0):

For setting up a notification for a specific pipeline, ds4940 is correct to filter for the definition name.  I would add - use "Contains" instead of "=".