# Azure DevOps. Get Discord Notification on Specific Pipeline Failure

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have a few pipelines that are taking backups on schedule. We would like to receive notifications on Discord in case if specific Pipelines were to fail.

There is a way to [receive an email notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56305482/email-notification-for-scheduled-build-that-failed-with-azure-devops-vsts) and an [official application to integrate Slack into Azure DevOps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56443273/get-notified-of-build-or-release-that-failed).

But is there a good way to do that for Discord?

Comment: As officially there is no default intergration with Discord. You can try with either Webhook or 3rd Party Services like Automate.io, zapier, Buddy.works etc.

Discord Webhook: https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook
Azure Webhook: https://github.com/pedroaraujo1952/AzureWebhook
Zapier: https://zapier.com/apps/azure-devops/integrations/discord
Automate.io: https://automate.io/integration/azure-devops/discord
Buddy.works: https://buddy.works/docs/api/pipelines/create-manage-actions/add-action/discord

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [Discord Webhook](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=robmburke.ado-discord-webhook) extension that give you a task to send messages to Discord during your pipeline.

When [creating a webhook](https://creating%20a%20webhook) for a channel in a Discord server, you will be given a url which contains the Channel ID and the Secret Key for that webhook in this format: `https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/{channelId}/{webhookKey}`.

You will not need to provide the url to the task, but rather just the Channel ID and Secret Key. (The first section in the link above, Making a Webhook, is all that needs to be followed to be able to use this task).

More info you can find [here](https://github.com/seraphx2/ado-discord-webhook).

After you know which values put in the task you can dd it to your pipeline and configure it to run only if the pipeline failed with the [condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) `failed()`.

Comment: Good approach! Is using an extension from Visual Studio Marketplace safe?

Comment: Yes, it's a popular extension and it's open source, so you can see the code :)